# Is DateTimeKind simply ignored when comparing times?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

```
var dt1 = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var dt2 = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
var dt3 = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

The result of pairwise comparisons became a surprise for me:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt1 == dt2); // true
Console.WriteLine(dt1 == dt3); // true
Console.WriteLine(dt2 == dt3); // true
```

Comment: [`DateTime.Equality`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx): "Before comparing `DateTime` objects, make sure that the objects represent times in the same time zone. You can do this by comparing the values of their `Kind` property."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever As usual, RTFM =) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [`Kind` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx) is ignored when you compare `DateTime` values.

From [referance source of `==` operator in `DateTime` structure](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1225):

```
public static bool operator ==(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    return d1.InternalTicks == d2.InternalTicks;
}
```

Also from [`DateTime.Compare` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx)<sup>1</sup>:

> To determine the relationship of `t1` to `t2`, the Compare method compares
>   the [`Ticks` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) of t1 and t2 **but ignores their Kind property**.
>   Before comparing DateTime objects, **ensure that the objects represent
>   times in the same time zone**.

1: <sup>which uses `==` operator internally</sup>

Comment: Indeed odd behavior. Recently we had an exception due to Unspecified time's kind. Don't remember exactly, where it occurred.